I have a .tex file i have to write in it
I need to write my B.s. thesis and my university provided a template as a .tex file. I don.t know how to open it, nor how to make edits. I just have been able to upload it. I use Overleaf

A .tex file is just an ordinary text file and can be opened with any text editor. I suggest you work yourself through a short course like learnlatex.org to get familiar with LaTeX.

Welcome. // You can open and edit it with any plain-text editor. To compile it you need a Latex installation, as Overleaf provides; they also have a more dedicated editor. Look for tutorials on OL. The template most likely will use standard Latex commands, perhaps with different layout and more functionality provided. Try getting a documentation of said template or ask one of your people at university. Try getting a book on Latex from your library.

I highly recommend Michelle Krummel's tutorial series: YouTube Link. It's an excellent resource for anyone beginning with LaTeX.

if you are using overleaf, there is an editor built in to teh website the left hand side is an editor, it you can write in this website you can werite in overleaf,  just using tex syntax rather than markdown

OTOH, there are (free) LaTeX specific editors which can proivde online help and menus of available math symbols.  I use TeXnicCenter.

I suggest to you start in Overleaf from scratch with a new .tex document containing just \documentclass{article} \begin{document} Hello, word \end{document}.  Once you realize that you can produce a PDF with this file, try to add common basic structures of any document (some paragraphs, a section title, a table, etc.) following some tutorial, and check the results of your experiments in the PDF.  Once you understand the basics, open your template, first check if it works "as is" and in this case, take care to add/replace text without breaking the existing code nor add mistyped commands.

Can you describe your problem opening the already uploaded file on overleaf? Does the file occur in your project? Can you select it? What happens, if you try to change the file contents shown in the editor view? Adding some screenshots could help. However, usually such questions are closed as off-topic, because you either have not read the tutorial or you have a specific overleaf problem and should contact the support.

Great you're already given a template. I can see that for a first time user, the learning curve may seem steep at first sight, but the past years have made that actually incredibly easy:
Contrasting the intimidating .tex template (or did you recieve a class or a style file?), there's the WYSIWYG (What you see is what you get) world of overleaf, handing you the ease of typing as you go and seeing the resulting text more or less simultaneously. They have written and compiled fantastic helping material which should make it really easy  eveb for a first-time user to get started.
Your probably best approach would be to devote a few hours into taking your first steps following their tutorial.
Don't worry about the files you were given for these hours, just get going with Overleaf and learn how their Interface is organized, where to write, how to download the resulting PDF, and how to download the entire project with all its files. They have linked to Learn Latex as well to teach you how to write style elements like headings, bullet points, footnotes and all the nifty details, but actually their first sample text should get you going for a start.
When after a session with their first sample/introductory text you feel a bit more comfortable with their Interface, it should either be clear to you how to set up the template you were given, or you could ask your tutor or the person who handed you the template to assist you in setting it up in Overleaf correctly.
Overleaf also has a great templates section, it may be that the template you need (and the accompanying style files) is already selectable there.Just give it a try.
You did not write what you have been given exactly - so I can only guess here.If it's "just a .tex file" things should have been quite straightforward. If you've been given the "whole package" of style/class and sample .tex file, I can see where it gets intimidating. So please familiarize yourself with Overleaf for a start - it's definitely worth the time spent, and should get yourself into a productive setup for your thesis quickly.
